# Changing decimal and group mark in rmarkdown render

Tags: r-markdown, knitr

I am working in RStudio (on a Mac) to write reports which are rendered as PDF.
I am working in an English locale.
The report, however, is in German and I would like to use German decimal and group (thousands) marks in the report without changing the locale of the OS (or R).
I would like to do this by setting one global option at the beginning of the Rmd file. 
Is there a way to accomplish this?

Up until now I tried

command line in Terminal
defaults write org.R-project.R force.LANG de_AT.UTF-8
This only changed the UI language used by R itself, no by RStudio.

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_NUMERIC","de_DE")
```

in an Rmd document produces

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ’sf': .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for ’units’, details: call:
>   udunits_initCfile.path(.get_ud_xml_dir(), "udunits2.xml")) error: Error in function udunits.init: Can't open
>   installed, default, unit database Execution halted

Putting
NUMERIC="de_DE"
LC_NUMERIC="de_DE"
in .Renviron does not help either

Comment: Can you add a [mre] showing what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting `?locales`

> Setting "LC_NUMERIC" to any value other than "C" may cause R to function anomalously, so gives a warning. Input conversions in R itself are unaffected, but the reading and writing of ASCII save files will be, as may packages which do their own input/output.
>
> Setting it temporarily on a Unix-alike to produce graphical or text output may work well enough, but options(OutDec) is often preferable.

So let's try that:

````
---
output: pdf_document
lang: de-DE
---

```{r echo=FALSE}
options(OutDec = ",")
library(sf)
knitr::kable(head(mtcars))
```

Dies ist ein nichtssagender Blindtext inklusive R output `r pi` der genau so
lang ist, dass es zu  Zeilenumbrüchen mit Trennung kommt.
````

Result:

[image]

Notes:

- There is no group-separator, since R does not use that in its output.
- I have added `lang: de-DE` to enable German hyphenation patterns.
- Loading the `sf` package works without problems.

Comment: That put me on the right track. But I am using `flextable` instead of `kable`, and the default for this is big.mark="," which in the md file produced warnings with lines beginning with # which broke TeX rendering. So I hat to add `colformat_num(...,big.mark=".")` for all calls to flextable, then things worked.

Comment: @ErichNeuwirth Great that you found a solution. Subtleties like this are the reason why I asked for a [mre].