# Rendering R markdown produces NaN from floating point numbers

Tags: r, r-markdown, model-fitting

**In a R markdown file**, I'm trying to fit a gaussian probability distribution to my data (financial returns) by the function `fitdist()` from the package `fitdistrplus`, this way:

```r
install.packages("fitdistrplus")
library(fitdistrplus)
returns <-c(1.1191,1.3674,1.4145,0.9196,0.7460,0.5555,0.9134,1.5428,0.9812,1.4667,1.3374,0.6447,1.3027,0.992,0.9028,0.8860,1.2057,1.2622,1.2036,1.3627,0.9134,1.0529,1.0539,1.1851,1.3220,1.2375,1.1864,0.9863,1.5259,1.3150,1.0650,0.8904,1.4357,1.1245,1.0033,1.2726,0.9124,1.2272,1.1657,1.1247,0.8985,1.2405,1.1103,0.9159,1.0405,1.1424,1.1906,0.8529,0.7357,1.3723,1.2391,0.9278,1.0653,1.1861,1.3245,0.9505,1.2175,1.2244,1.0636,1.3208,1.1843,1.0528,1.1683,1.3141,0.9682,1.3060,1.0769,1.0993,1.0130,1.3757,1.2307,1.3327,1.2858,1.2104,0.9089,0.8811,0.7790,1.2215,1.0607,1.0395,1.0539,1.1118,0.5122,1.3713,1.1791) 
norm.f <- fitdist(data = returns, distr = "norm")
```

I get the warning: `NaN produced`. Quite strange.
But, if I run the **same** code from within **an R file** (and NOT an R Markdown file) everything works.
Any suggestions, please?

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem, it works without warnings for me in interactive mode and in a rmd file.  Can you give the complete code for a small .rmd file that reproduces this problem?

Comment: Like George Savva, your code renders fine with markdown on my system. Do your system settings use a different symbol (than the point) as default decimal separator and, hence,  `rmarkdown::render` not recognise the number? If so, this question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58288563/changing-decimal-and-group-mark-in-rmarkdown-render

Comment: If you still can't figure it out and the only problem is the warning (i.e. the actual numerical results are identical), you could use chunk option `warn=FALSE` (I think: maybe `warning=FALSE`?) to suppress the warning ...